# How to randomly select some pandas dataframe rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which contains a column `amount`.  For many rows, the `amount` is zero.  I want to randomly remove 50% of the rows where the `amount` is zero, keeping all rows where `amount` is nonzero.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `pandas`

Using `query` + `sample`

```
df.drop(df.query('amount == 0').sample(frac=.5).index)
```

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(amount=[0, 1] * 10))

df.drop(df.query('amount == 0').sample(frac=.5).index)
```

## `numpy`

```
iszero = df.amount.values == 0
count_zeros = iszero.sum()
idx = np.arange(iszero.shape[0])
keep_these = np.random.choice(idx[iszero], int(iszero.sum() * .5), replace=False)

df.iloc[np.sort(np.concatenate([idx[~iszero], keep_these]))]
```

---

```
    amount
1        1
2        0
3        1
5        1
6        0
7        1
8        0
9        1
10       0
11       1
12       0
13       1
15       1
17       1
19       1
```

---

***time test***

[image]

Per the comment from @tomcy, you can use the parameter `inplace=True` to remove the rows from `df` without having to reassign `df`

```
df.drop(df.query('amount == 0').sample(frac=.5).index, inplace=True)
df

    amount
1        1
2        0
3        1
5        1
6        0
7        1
8        0
9        1
10       0
11       1
12       0
13       1
15       1
17       1
19       1
```

​

Comment: `inplace` parameter should be `True`

Comment: FWIW, doing a boolean selection seems about twice as fast as query (of course still slower than numpy):  `df.drop( df[df.amount == 0].sample(frac=.5).index )`

Comment: @JohnE Yeah!  I figured that if I'm going to stray from my beloved `query` for speed, I might as well go all the way :-).  Plus... it leaves open the opportunity for someone else to post that answer, if you catch my drift.  OP may even like that answer better.

Comment: Ha, alright, I'll write it up as a tweak of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

A minor tweak on @piRSquared's answer (using a boolean selection instead of query):

```
df.drop( df[df.amount == 0].sample(frac=.5).index )
```

It's about twice as fast as using query, but 3x slower than the numpy way.

Comment: This is great because often people want a more intuitive `pandas` answer.  Some might even prefer the syntax of this over `query`.

Comment: OP here. This is an excellent answer, and I use it in my code. I wasn't sure which response to mark as the answer, but I went with the one with the numpy solution since it was so thorough.

Comment: @royco Thanks, no worries.  You made the right choice.  I merely did a minor tweak to piRSquared's answer